# Extra form fields not bound to model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I retrieve a form value in the controller, when the specific field is no field of the model?

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="updateUser()">
       //fields of model
       <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.first_name" required/>

       //not bound to model
       <input type="password" name="password"/>
       <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"/>
 </form>
```

In the controller:

```
 console.log($scope.password);
```

returns **undefined**. Is it possible to get the passwords without modifing the user resource?

Comment: you could query it, but better just bind it to something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `ng-model="password"`, it'll get added to the scope but not `$scope.user`:

```html
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" />
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="password_confirmation" />
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I do so console returns undefined

Comment: Hey please have a look at http://embed.plnkr.co/3lOCLg5jwnqQrBQwyrjJ/preview . In my case it is not working

Comment: Just type in a first and a last name, then try the password

Comment: change `ng-model="old_password"` to `ng-model="password"`: http://plnkr.co/edit/cmri1HYZogWWSnhnnqLC?p=preview